Backup Dynamo DB data using AWS Firehose
I have enabled a Kinesis stream on my DynamoDB table, which is then used by Firehose to back up the data to S3. Now, I want to enable it for multiple tables, but I need a separate folder for each table inside my S3 bucket.
I can't enable dynamic partitioning in Firehose because the partition key is same in some of the table
What can I do to overcome this situation?

you can use Separate Firehose Delivery Streams for Each DynamoDB Table
or
Create Lambda function for Dynamic Partitioning Based on Table Name.

Creating different firehose delivery for every table would be bad it will increase the costing.Lambda part can you explain in brief?

You can use an AWS Lambda function to modify the records and include the table name as part of the S3 prefix or partition key.
Attach the Lambda function to the Kinesis Stream. This function can add an attribute to each record indicating the source DynamoDB table name.
Then, configure the Firehose delivery stream to use a prefix pattern that includes this new attribute. For example:
Set the prefix pattern as !{table_name}/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/.
This way, all records are routed to separate folders within your S3 based on their originating table.

But my source of firehose is kinesis can i use this lambda in data transformation of firehose cause there i have attribute tableName?
